# hibernate jpa could not determine data type for simple case statement

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am having a query which works fine in sql but in hibernate it fails with could not determine data type for simple case

below is part of my query which is having problem

```
        + "AND CASE common.key WHEN '100' THEN so.sdate      "
        + "                                       WHEN '101' THEN so.sdate   "
        + "                                       WHEN '102'  THEN co.edate      "
        + "                                       WHEN '103' THEN co.edate END "
        + "<= "
        + "CASE commonkey WHEN '100' THEN CONVERT(DATE,:input1) "
        + "                                   WHEN '101' THEN CONVERT(DATE,:input2)    "
        + "                                   WHEN '102' THEN CONVERT(DATE,:input3)               "
        + "                                   ELSE CONVERT(DATE,:input4)           END "
```

This query works fine in jpa if i remove case in 2nd part ie is if i directly give the value without case. Only if i give it in case (which i have to) then its throwing this error

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you running this as a native query?

Comment: No I am not. I want it to run as normal jpa query. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: No I want to run this as jpl query. Is there anything wrong in this query?

Comment: I wonder what the actual error message is (and exception + stack trace) ... And then you ignore the requirement for any CASE statement to have an ELSE (the first CASE). Why your JPA provider doesn't tell you that, you'd have to raise with them. Then you have the problem of `CONVERT` not being a valid JPQL function ...